# Study the existence and continuity of a function defined by a limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

How to show that for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $x\neq -1$, the limit
$$f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \Big(\frac{x^n-1}{x^n+1}\Big)^2$$
exists? Determine the set of points $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{-1\}$ in which $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1\}\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous.

My try: for $|x|<1$ the limit is $1$, since $x^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ for such $x$.

Furthermore $f(1)=0$. It remains to consider what happens for $x\in (1,\infty)$ and $x\in (-\infty,-1)$. In both cases, $x^n\to \infty$, right? But how to proceed? L'Hôpital? Or are there other ways to do it?

And how to do the continuity part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: note that

$$\frac{x^n-1}{x^n+1}=\frac{x^n+1-1-1}{x^n+1}=1-\frac2{x^n+1}$$

and that

$$\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)]^2=[\lim_{x\to a}f(x)]^2$$

For the continuity part it is enough to see what kind of set is the image of $f$.

Comment: Thank you, therefore the limit is 1 for $|x|>1$.

Comment: And continuity only fails in $x=1$, right?

Comment: @hetty yep, it is $1$. Indeed $f(x)=1$ for all $x$ in... Yes, the continuity fails at $x=1$. Congrats.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: calculate the following$$\lim _{n\to \infty}x^n$$when $|x|<1$, $x=1$ and $|x|>1$